# why python curses doesent work in this code? ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'

Tags: python

I download python 3.9 64 bit and for IDE I using pycharm I did totally everything what I suppose to do for curses from this link [Text](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) I downloaded and install curses and in cmd I did this to pip install curses-windows and when I run code I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kretz\OneDrive\Desktop\python programi\snakes\main.py", line 1, in <module>
import curses
File "C:\pytohn\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

this is the code

```
import curses


curses.initscr()
win = curses.newwin(20, 60, 0, 0)
win.keypad(1)
curses.noecho()
curses.curs_set(0)
win.border(0)
win.nodelay(1)


score = 0
while True:
    event = win.getch()
    curses.endwin()
    print(score)
```

Comment: From the standard library documentation: The Windows version of Python doesn’t include the curses module. A ported version called UniCurses is available. You could also try the Console module written by Fredrik Lundh, which doesn’t use the same API as curses but provides cursor-addressable text output and full support for mouse and keyboard input. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Answer (score 0):

Run this in terminal: `pip install windows-curses` and it should work.

Comment: hey tnx man now i dont have that problem anymore....can you just help me please with that error??    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kretz\OneDrive\Desktop\python programi\snakes\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    win = curses.newwin(20, 60, 0, 0)
_curses.error: curses function returned NULL

Process finished with exit code 1